# Comments from post not displaying correctly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Been trying to set up a regular blog in Ruby on Rails, and finally got the comment system to work within a post. However, when I loop through each comment and try to output the comment's title it displays this,

```
awef [#<Comment id: 6, title: "awef", link: nil, campaign_id: 5, user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-09-24 09:46:43", updated_at: "2015-09-24 09:46:43">]
```

Instead of just the title. How can I fix this?

Comment: please show your code to us

Comment: Can you show the actual loop?

Comment: <%= @blog.comments.each do |f| %>
<%= f.title.to_s %>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you have is probably the `=` in your `each` statement.

Try to use this:

```
<% @blog.comments.each do |f| %> 
  <%= f.title %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the removed `=` at `<% @blog.comments.each do |f| %>`

The reason is as the `<%= %>` always prints while `<% %>` only executes the code.

Comment: Thanks! this fixed it!

Comment: The first part of this answer is completely misleading, not to say wrong! Why should he override a default method?

Comment: He doesn't have to. I understood the question wrong before the formatting was fixed in the edit. I thought he just displayed `comment` in the loop, in which case he could overwrite the `to_s` method in the Comment model to display whatever he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @blog.comments.each do |f| %> # remove "="

  <%= f.title %>

<% end %>
```

`<% ... %>`: Executes the ruby code within the brackets

`<%= ...%>`: Executes the ruby code and show the executing result in webpage

Answer (score 0):

The loop in your view should be something like this:

```
<% @blog.comments.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.title %>
<% end %>
```

Please check you are using the right angular parenthesis (<%= %>) and not placing `p` `puts` or `inspect` commands inside them.

**Edit:**
Now that you show use the code, the problem is in the first angular parenthesis: should be `<%` not `<%=`. The first is for the logic, the latter to output erb code.

Answer (score 0):

Classic mistake, it's because you're using `<%=` ERB output tags for the `.each` loop.  You can [view more information on how to write correct ERB here](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/).

You need to replace your `<%=` output tags with standard ERB tags `<%`:

```
<% @blog.comments.each do |f| %>
```

I was stung by that one myself when I was starting out.